# How to measure length of an html page and conditionally redirect to home page

Tags: java, html, redirect

How do you measure length of an html page and redirect to home page if its size is less than 1000 characters with Java?

In my case there a page of a form indexed by the google no longer  exist and I want to be aware how to redirect all such mostly blank pages to homepage. It's installed to a hosting of another company therefore there some limitations to test something else.

Comment: There is a lot of possible solutions - do you dare to tell about technology you use for serving webpages?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Use a library like [Apache a HttpComponent](http://hc.apache.org/) (here is an [example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)) or standard java [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)
2. Fire a Get/Post (which ever applicable).
3. Get the response and measure its length.

or

1. Fire a Head request.
2. Get the response and measure the value of `Content-Length` header in response.